# How can i hide the Page Title in Site Master Page not for System Master Page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage

I just created the Custom master page and added below code for showing the page Title

**Note:** Custem Master page to set **Site Master Page** and **System Master Page**

```
<h1 id="pageContentTitle" class="ms-belltown-pageName ms-noWrap custom-page-title ms-dialogHidden">
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
    <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb runat="server" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" WelcomePageUsesWebTitle="false">-->
    <!--SPM:<PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server"/>-->
    <!--SPM:</PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>-->
    <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
    </h1>
```

But The problem is  Page Title **should show System Master Page** and **doesn't show Site Master Page**.

Is this Possible to achieve by using CSS only ? or SharePoint Provide any specific class for that ?

I tried but i didn't get any proper answer for that situation, can you help me in that situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your master page's stylesheet, use

```
span#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea {
    visibility: hidden;
}
span#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea span {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Edit: found out this doesn't work at least on `/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`. Looking for a better solution.

---

As the above CSS-change has its varying results, you could more efficiently do this in jQuery as suggested in the other answer. For what I've witnessed, Site Master Pages include the `/Pages/` in their URL. Thus you could do this followingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript "src="http://sharepoint/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js" </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var path = window.location.pathname;
if (pathname.indexOf("/Pages/") >= 0)
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: I tried as per your comments but it doesn't working  proper, sometimes Breadcrumb arrow is showing.. @moe

Comment: @RaviDelixan I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some ways to solve this:

- Use a secondary .master without the title / with an extra css class
- A tiny .js that is checking if the current page is a system page and adds the corresponding css class

Example:

```
var isSystemPage = function(){
  return (!_spPageContextInfo.pageListId && !_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId && !location.href.indexOf('_layouts/15/') !== -1);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your quick reply, i don't want to use  secondary .master.

Comment: How i am going to achieve this (checking if the current page is a system page) ? can you explain bit more @mx.

Comment: @RaviDelixan I updated my answer